# AdSense ads not working after redirecting Blogger to a custom domain

Tags: blogger, google-adsense, google-custom-search

AdSense ads are not showing after I redirected my blog to a custom domain.

- Blogger URL: http://sandeeppateltechblogs.blogspot.com
- Custom Domain URL: http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/

How can I make it display the ads again?

Comment: According to Googles policies, ads from different ad networks shouldn't look the same as their ads. You have an ad block from an ad network called Chitika on the bottom of your site. While Chitika's homepage says their ads look different from Google's ads, they look similar to me - I was about to comment that I can see a Google adsense unit on your blog. So maybe that is the problem, and not the domain?

Comment: You need to get the usual approval from AdSense team for your custom domain.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

I had a blogger blog, and using Google's options, I redirected it to a real www.example.com domain.

Now, AdSense ads would not show up on my blog.

Solution:

1. In Blogger dashboard, I clicked on Earnings.
2. In the main menu, I clicked on "My Ads".
3. The screen says, "Content > URL Channels"
4. On this screen, I clicked "+ New URL Channel"

   1. I typed in my new URL - the new .com one I purchased.
   2. Clicked Save and Bingo! - The AdSense ads now appear on my blog.

Comment: How long it's take to display the ads?

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of possibilities here.

**First**, inside AdSense, have you restricted the sites that your ads can be shown on?  Have you added your new custom-domain to that list?

**Second**, when did you sign up for AdSense?   If it was after early November 2012, then you probably went through the fast-track sign-up process for host-partner publishers.   I'm not certain, but it's possible that with a custom domain you need to go through the full sign-up process, even though you're still publishing via a host partner.  I've put some links about this into a brief description of this change, here:   http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/simpler-but-more-limited-adsense-sign.html

**Third**, have you changed any aspects of your template or layout at the same time as doing the re-direction?   It's possible that the AdSense problem is co-incidental.   Assuming that you have ...

When I look at your blog with IE9, at the bottom I see ad-units from Chitika and Infolinks, and a square at the very bottom of the page with a "could not load" message.    Looking at the page source, I can see that there is reference to an AdSense ad unit there.   When I look at it in Chrome (latest version) I see a blank space there.

How did you put the AdSense ad unit in to your blog?   Some options / suggestions:

A)    Using **Dashboard > Layout > Add a Gadget > AdSense** tool inside Blogger?   If so, go and ask for help in the Blogger Product Forum, this problem is likely to be about far more than just you!

B)    Using **Dashboard > Layout > Add a Gadget > HTML/Javascript** tool inside Blogger?   Are you 100% sure that you copied the ad-code correctly from AdSense and pasted it as is, with no changes, to the gadget's Content field?

C)   By editing your template directly and pasting in the ad-code from AdSense?    If so, did you "escape" the code before pasting it in?   (I'm guessing from your blog content that you know what this means).

**Fourth:**   I don't believe that there is any conflict with Chitika:  have have AdSense and Chitika units on the same page, and don't run into problems.    However I don't know about InfoLinks.  Have you tried putting the AdSense ad above them, to see if the order makes a difference?   (I won't solve your underlying problem, but may give some clues.)

Sorry that this is not a clear solution, but hopefully something here gives you a clue about how to proceed.

Comment: I checked my site properly according to your guidelines. Still I am not able to see the ads.I posted in ad sense forum also,but no use. Can you please help further to nail down this issue.

Comment: When did you sign up for AdSense initially?

Answer (score 0):

After changing my blog from

```
Blogger URL: http://wereya.blogspot.com
Custom Domain URL: <http://www.wereya.com>
```

You don't need to correct the codes of Adsense if you add the codes onto the side-bar on your blog since the side-bar is using HTML/Javascript which is not allow xml.

But if you go to Dashboard > Design > Edit HTML (This HTML editor allows xml), you need to modify the codes of Adsense:

1. Change `&` into `&amp;`
2. Change `<` into `&lt;`
3. Change `>` into `&gt;`
4. Change `"` into `&quot;`
5. Change `'` into `&apos;`

For example, the blue codes below is original codes of Adsense, and the yellow codes below is what I have after changed all the symbols:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-0690220431785051";
/* 728x90, created 8/7/10 */
google_ad_slot = "8652075993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>

&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;!--
google_ad_client = &quot;pub-0690220431785051";
/* 728x90, created 8/7/10 */
google_ad_slot = &quot;8652075993&quot;;
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//--&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;
src=&quot;http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js&quot;&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work after when your new custom domain is approved from **Google Adsense**. your Blogspot domain may be approved but custom domain also require Approval.